# Nsight Eclipse Cuda + opencv

Tags: eclipse, opencv, cuda, clang, nsight

I installed nsight with cuda5.5. Everything works fine but I am trying to run opencv functions on the host to generate images.
I include opencv header path and also the libs paths that I need. When I try to compile it gives this error `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/clang/5.0/include/emmintrin.h(274): error: identifier "__builtin_ia32_cmpsd" is undefined`
Anyone knows what could be the reason? Or any way to have make opencv work with nsight eclipse? 
Thanks!

Comment: I don't think that your error depends on cuda or opencv. For me it seems to be problem with clang. Propably it's only missing a linked library from there.

Comment: I would second @hubs in that this looks like OpenCV issue with Clang.

Comment: @hubs How did you solve your problem?

Comment: @RosePerrone I didn't solve this problem. I wanted only to note, that this problem doesn't relate to nsight eclipse, cude or opencv. I think there is missing a link against a clang library.

Answer (score 1):

I solved my issue by removing the '-D HAVE_SSE2' from the macros defined in config.mk.

If you can't do that:

See [this solution](http://www.herikstad.net/2009/05/cuda-and-sse2-intrinsics.html). In brief, you need to compile the code using SSE2 using gcc and your CUDA code using nvcc and then link them together afterwards.

Apparently NVidia [is aware of the problem](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/539513/nvcc-compile-errors-when-using-sse-intrinsic-functions-with-gcc-as-host-compiler/) and "it should be fixed soon", but I have v6.0 and the bug still exists.

Someone [mentioned this problem on the NVIDIA developer forums](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/733135/nvcc-compile-errors-with-with-cuda-6-0-clang-os-x-10-9-when-including-boost-function-or-opencv/?offset=2#4226331), but nobody replied.